# cython/python: how to catch as exception an external function that "exits" instead of "returns"

Tags: python, cython

I'm using Cython to interface an external C function.  The function (a science code with 100k code lines) internally checks for invalid conditions and "exits" if they occur.

How can I get Cython to detect and raise an exception when the external function "exits" instead of "returns"?

**Edit:** user2864740 is right, cython actually exits.  (I was running the function inside a python mulitprocessing.Process.  To simplify I got rid of multiprocessing.)  The question now is:

How can I prevent the "exit()" call from the external library to exit Cython (or Python, at a later point).  A try-except construct doesn't catch this.  Can this be caught as exception instead of the whole process dying?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit surprised that doesn't also exit Cython..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are guidelines for "Joining zombie processes" in the `multiprocessing` documentation.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines
If in the master process you find that the worker process is defunct, you can raise an exception.

Alternatively you could try registering an `atexit` handler from within the Cython code
http://linux.die.net/man/3/atexit

A third idea is to use some kind of `LD_PRELOAD` library to override the `exit` function so that it raises a Python exception.

Comment: I cannot get an atexit function to be executed after the "exit" in the external library, just like a try-except construction doesn't catch the exception.  The third suggestion works, of course, but it's the least favorable.  The question remains: how to catch the "exit" exception...